# $e^{2\sigma x^2}<\left(\frac{m+\sigma x^2}{m-\sigma x^2}\right)^m<\left(\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}\right)^\sigma.$

Tags: inequality

Let $\lambda>0$ and $0<\sigma<m$, then
$$\exp{\frac{2\lambda\sigma}{2+\lambda}}<\left(\frac{m(2+\lambda)+\lambda\sigma}{m(2+\lambda)-\lambda\sigma}\right)^m<(1+\lambda)^\sigma,$$
where the outermost functions do not depend on $m$ in which case $\sigma,\lambda>0$. Furthermore, let $x\in(-1,1)\setminus\{0\}$ and let $\lambda=2x^2/(1-x^2)$, then we obtain the more compact form
$$e^{2\sigma x^2}<\left(\frac{m+\sigma x^2}{m-\sigma x^2}\right)^m<\left(\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}\right)^\sigma.$$

Is my proof correct ?

**Proof**

Consider the obvious inequality $x^2(m^2-\sigma^2)>0$ where $x>0$ and $0<\sigma<m$. Adding $4(1+xm)$ to both sides gives
$$4+2x(m+\sigma)+2x(m-\sigma)+x^2(m^2-\sigma^2)>4(1+xm),$$
and factorising,
$$(2+x(m-\sigma))(2+x(m+\sigma))>4(1+xm).$$
Multiplying by $4m\sigma$ and rearranging,
$$\frac{m\sigma}{1+xm}-\frac{4m\sigma}{(2+x(m-\sigma))(2+x(m+\sigma)}>0.$$
Then
$$\int_0^x\frac{m\sigma}{1+tm}dt-\int_0^x\frac{4m\sigma}{(2+t(m-\sigma))(2+t(m+\sigma)}dt>0.$$
Since $\log(1+ym)=0$ for $y=0$ then
$$\sigma\log(1+mx)-m\log\left(\frac{2+x(m+\sigma)}{2+x(m-\sigma)}\right)>0.$$
Rearranging and exponentiating gives
$$(1+mx)^\sigma>\left(\frac{2+x(m+\sigma)}{2+x(m-\sigma)}\right)^m.$$
Now let $\lambda=mx$ and notice that
$$\frac{2+\lambda+x\sigma}{2+\lambda-x\sigma}=\frac{2+\lambda+\lambda\sigma/m}{2+\lambda-\lambda\sigma/m}=\frac{m(2+\lambda)+\lambda\sigma}{m(2+\lambda)-\lambda\sigma},$$
as required.

For the lower bound, taking the limit as $m\to\infty$ gives the exponential inequality.

**Corollaries**

1. Let $f(x)>0$ and $0<g(x)<1$, then
   $$(1+f(x))^{g(x)}>\frac{2+f(x)(1+g(x))}{2+f(x)(1-g(x))}.$$
2. Let $0<x<1$, then
   $$(1+x)^x>\frac{2+x+x^2}{2+x-x^2}\implies(1+x)^{1+x}>\frac{2+x+x^2}{2-x}.$$
3. Let $f(x)>0$, $x>0$, then $$\sqrt{1+f(x)}>\frac{3f(x)+4}{f(x)+4}.$$
4. Let $x>0$, then $$\sqrt{1+x}>\frac{3x+4}{x+4}.$$
5. Let $x=e-1$ and $0<\sigma<1$. Then
   $$e^\sigma>\frac{2+(e-1)(1+\sigma)}{2+(e-1)(1-\sigma)}.$$
6. $$\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}>\frac{3\tan^2\theta+4}{\tan^2\theta+4}\implies|\sec\theta|>\frac{3\tan^2\theta+4}{\tan^2\theta+4}=\frac{3\sec^2\theta+1}{\sec^2\theta+3}=\frac{3+\cos^2\theta}{1+3\cos^2\theta}$$
   $$\int_0^t|\sec \theta|d\theta>\frac{t}{3}-\frac{4}{3} \tan ^{-1}(2 \cot t)+\frac{2 \pi }{3}.$$
7. Let $\sin\theta\neq 0$. $$(1+\sin^2\theta)^\sigma>\frac{2+\sin^2\theta(1+\sigma)}{2+\sin^2\theta(1-\sigma)}.$$
8. Let $\cos\theta\neq 0$. $$(1+\cos^2\theta)^\sigma>\frac{2+\cos^2\theta(1+\sigma)}{2+\cos^2\theta(1-\sigma)}.$$
9. Combining these two gives
   $$1>\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{2+\sin^2\theta(1+\sigma)}{2+\sin^2\theta(1-\sigma)}\right)^\frac{1}{\sigma}+\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{2+\cos^2\theta(1+\sigma)}{2+\cos^2\theta(1-\sigma)}\right)^\frac{1}{\sigma}.$$
10. Let $\sin\theta\neq 0$, then $$(1+\sin^2\theta)^{\cos^2\varphi}>\frac{2+\sin^2\theta(1+\cos^2\varphi)}{2+\sin^2\theta\sin^2\varphi}.$$